# Why are another user's changes now appearing as my changes?

Tags: git

This has happened a couple of times now - another user has created a branch and then merged that branch with the master/HEAD. I then commit my local changes (in this case 1 file), and try to push them, but push fails because it's out of sync. So, I pull from the repo and it pulls in the current master/HEAD which includes the changes made in the other user's branch. Now, when I go to push again, it fails saying that I have uncommitted changes (and lists all the changes in that other user's branch!) - why is it telling me to commit the other user's changes? They're not my changes!

Something doesn't seem right, I can't even pull now, it fails because apparently my local changes would be overwritten by merge (listing the changes which arent mine!)

I am new to Git, but still, this doesn't seem right....

Comment: Did you get a merge conflict by any chance when you `pull`ed?

Comment: Agree with @Shahbaz.  The only reason the other user's changes would show up as uncommitted is if there was a conflict when you tried to merge them.  You have to resolve the conflict and then use `git add` to tell git the conflict is resolved before they can be committed.

Comment: This is the thing - the pull was fine - no errors, i use TortoiseGit and you can't miss it when there are conflicts. It was only when i tried to push my earlier commit that it failed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit the merge.   When you pull, there were probably conflicts which need to be resolved and comitted locally before you push.

Comment: There couldn't be any conflicts though - i had only changed one file - and that wasn't in the other user's list of changes!

Comment: Did you try pushing the entire branch, or just your changed file?  It may work if you just commit and push your one changed file (since it is not affected by the other persons changes), then pull all of the other changes, or do a checkout.

Comment: Sorted it. I just forced a checkout to FETCH_HEAD, performed another pull, switched to master (is that normal to have to do that?), then performed a push which pushed my original commit (of one file).

Thanks for all your help folks